# Is there a way to run an XWindow program with out a desktop manager?

Tags: vnc

I need to run a program over VNC, but don't want the Desktop Manager or Window Manager to run. Can the .xstartup program be configured that way?

PS. I am sure I have done it before whilst conducting some experiments. It was a long time ago and I just can't remember how.

Answer (score 1):

Rather then using VNC which afaik requires a window manager on the remote server, run an Xserver locally (in X windowing language the server runs on the side of the monitor/display, not on the remote server the X server runs on your workstation.) and use SSH with X forwarding.

If you don't already run X on your workstation (eg you're running MS Windows) there should be a couple of free and open source ones which work well enough.

Then make sure xauth is available on your server and ,log in with `ssh -X` and start your X application.

Comment: I have been able to run the program without the window manager. I disabled some settings in the `.vnc/xstartup` file. Thanks anyway. I just am looking for more authoritative answer on how all the processes fit together